# Dependent types and polymorphism in Python with mypy

Tags: python, typing, dependent-type, mypy

For the following example, `mypy` returns an error:

> error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "A",
>   variable has type "A1")

```py
from typing import Type

class A:
    pass

class A1(A):
    pass

class A2(A):
    pass

def fun(A_type: Type[A]) -> A:
    if A_type == A1:
        return A1()
    else:
        return A2()

a1: A1 = fun(A1)
```

What I would ideally like to do is to enforce a dependency in the signature of `fun`:

```py
def fun(A_type: Type[A]) -> A_type
```

Is this possible; if not, what is recommended (note: I want this to work for as yet undefined sub-classes of `A`, so I don't think I can use the `overload` decorator)?  Is my best option just to use `cast`?

Comment: Just as an FYI, "dependent types" isn't quite the right phrase to use here. "Dependent types" is a formal term used to describe types that can depend on *values*: e.g. types that can say things like "this must be exactly the number 3" or "this can be any odd integer" or "this can be any non-empty list of strings". Mypy currently supports this only in a very very limited way via the [`Literal[...]` type](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/literal_types.html). Rather, what you're looking for here is something known as [*generics*](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html).

Comment: Isn't it dependent because the return type of the function depends on values of the arguments to the function (which in this case happen to be types)?

Comment: Not really, because you're not trying to express any particular constraint about the different values `A_type` can have. Rather, all you're trying to say is "I want a function `(Type[T]) -> T` where T is *parameterizable*" -- where when you actually call your function, you parameterize the signature by substituting every occurrence of T with some other type. You actually don't really care what gets substituted, except that it's upper-bounded by A (is either A or a subtype of A). This can be accomplished purely by looking at types and so doesn't need the power of a dependent type system.

Comment: OK then I must misunderstand what dependent types means.  I thought it meant `f(x: t) -> r(x, t)` for some function `r`, which depends on both `x` and `t`.  And I thought `f` is generic in `t` when `r` is a function of `t` only, and doesn't depend on `x`.  In my case `r(A_type, A) = A_type` so it depends on `x`, to the left of the colon in the type signature

Comment: I think here in Python, every type is also a value (`List[int]`, `List[str]`, `float`). And each of these "type" values has a different type. Like the type of value `List[int]` is `Type[List[int]]` and no other value has this type. Unlike the case where 1,2,3 are all of the type `int`. So in this sense it's not dependent typing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a TypeVar with a bound on it:

https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generics.html#type-variables-with-upper-bounds

```
from typing import Type, TypeVar

class A:
    pass

class A1(A):
    pass

class A2(A):
    pass

T_A = TypeVar('T_A', bound='A')

def fun(A_type: Type[T_A]) -> T_A:
    if A_type == A1:
        r1 = A1()
        assert isinstance(r1, A_type)
        return r1
    else:
        r2 = A2()
        assert isinstance(r2, A_type)
        return r2

a1: A1 = fun(A1)
a2: A2 = fun(A2)
print("winner winner chicken dinner")
```

typechecks clean and runs without failing either type assert:

```
C:\test\python>mypy polymorph.py
Success: no issues found in 1 source file

C:\test\python>python polymorph.py
winner winner chicken dinner
```

In this example the type `T_A` is required to be a subclass of `A`, but it's a *particular* type, and the typing of `fun` requires that it returns the same type it receives as an argument.

Unfortunately the static type checker isn't *quite* smart enough to bind the type unless you add the runtime assert in there (there might be some way to do this better with the `Generic` type but it eludes me).

Comment: But `A_type` is a type, not an instance of type `A` so this introduces more errors.

Comment: In your example `fun` returns an instance of type `A`, not a type, so it's not clear to me what it is you're actually trying to do.

Comment: I want to specify that `fun` returns an object of type `A_type` (which is a subclass of `A`), not just of type `A` so that the final line `a1: A1 = fun(A1)` type checks; i.e. so that `fun(A1)` is guaranteed, for example, to have all the methods of `A1` (which may not be present in an object of type `A` or `A2`).  Obviously this is a highly contrived example.

Comment: Basically, I want to define a polymorphic function `fun` so that both `a1: A1 = fun(A1)` and `a2: A2 = fun(A2)` and so on for all possible subclasses of `A` typecheck without error in `mypy`

Comment: Ah, got it.  Took me a bit of fiddling but I worked out how to do this, updating answer.  :)

Comment: The reason the type-checker won't refine the type of `A_type` after you do `A_type == A1` is because the `__eq__` method could potentially be overridden to do arbitrary things, making it untrustworthy for the purposes of type-checking. It's generally better to use `isinstance(...)` or `issubclass(...)` instead. Those are also technically overridable, but almost nobody does so mypy treats those as fair game out of practicality.

Comment: That said, having if/else statements at all is probably a mistake since it forces the code to handle only a finite set of subclasses, defeating the purpose. You probably want to instead just do `return A_type()` instead, making the function a one-liner. And if you want even more precision, make `A_type` be of type `Callable[[], T_A]` instead of `Type[T_A]` so we can enforce that the constructor is what you expect (and open up the possibility of passing in custom functions instead of just constructors).

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but for completeness' sake I would like to add that you can also use `typing.overload`, like this:

```py
from typing import Type, overload

class A:
    pass

class A1(A):
    pass

class A2(A):
    pass

@overload
def fun(A_type: Type[A1]) -> A1: ...

@overload
def fun(A_type: Type[A2]) -> A2: ...

def fun(A_type: Type[A]) -> A:
    if A_type == A1:
        return A1()
    else:
        return A2()

a1: A1 = fun(A1)
```

This precisely describes the typing for the two variants. As both an upside and downside of this approach, you'll have to explicitly add another overload for every inheriting class you want to support. Contrast with the bounded TypeVar approach, which automatically annotates the function for use with all inheriting classes. So I guess which approach is preferable still depends on the context and your preferences.

As a sidenote, remember that Python does not really support overloading. There can only be one implementation, so only the last `def fun(...` definition is what is actually executed when you call `fun(...)` in your code.
The actual implementation (without the `@overload`) comes last. The `@overload` decorator itself is only there as a "tag", so the type checker knows it has to take into account these overloads (instead of overriding them with the last implementation like the interpreter does)