# Mypy incompatible type when passing parent and child classes as varaibles

Tags: python, generics, inheritance, mypy

I have a parent class and child class, defined as such:

```
class Parent:
    some_attr: str

class Child1(Parent):
    some_attr = 'foo'

class Child2(Parent):
    some_attr = 'bar'
```

I then have a mapping dictionary that maps a key to the child types, like so:

```
lookup_dict: dict[str, type[Parent]] = {
    'child1': Child1,
    'child2': Child2,
}
```

I then have functions that accept the type of the child classes as arguments:

```
def child1_function(typ: type[Child1]) -> None:
    ...

def child2_function(typ: type[Child2]) -> None:
    ...
```

And another function that accepts a key in the lookup dict as an argument, finds the child type in the lookup dict, and passes that type into one of the child functions depending on the value of its `some_attr`:

```
def parent_function(key: str) -> None:
    typ = lookup_dict[key]
    if typ.some_attr == 'foo':
        child1_function(typ)  # Argument 1 to 
"child1_function" has incompatible type "type[Parent]"; expected "type[Child1]"  [arg-type]
    if typ.some_attr == 'bar':
        child2_function(typ)  # Argument 1 to 
"child2_function" has incompatible type "type[Parent]"; expected "type[Child2]"  [arg-type]
```

This obviously generates a mypy error that the types are incompatible.

I'm a bit stumped. Any suggestions are welcome

I've tried defining the Parent as a generic with a typevar, like so:

```
PT = TypeVar("PT", bound="Parent")

class Parent(Generic[PT]):
    ...
```

then defining the lookup_dict like:

```
lookup_dict: dict[str, type[PT]] = {
    ...
}
```

But this produced a new error that `PT` is unbound (which I'm confused by since I specified a type bound...)

Basically what I want is a dictionary that holds children of `Parent` where `child_function` does not complain that it is not receiving the `Parent` type

Comment: What is `type[Child]` supposed to mean? You have not defined anything named `Child`.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion, I've made some edits to clarify my question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58675911/dependent-types-and-polymorphism-in-python-with-mypy I think this has been answered here?